# How to find corresponding max value in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have obtained data from UV/Vis

[image: UV/VIS]

My Goal is to find a wavelength after 330nm and find the maximum absorbance. So in this case the highest value would be around 0.4 at 420nm

CSV file looks like this

```
Wavelength (nm) Absorbance (AU) Std.Dev.
190 2.458802223 0.012281572
191 2.523416042 0.011004285
192 2.609054089 0.014727822 
193 2.6453619   0.00920296
.
.
```

and so on

Here is my code

```
import os
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np

Rhod = open('Rhodamine.CSV', 'r+')
text = Rhod.read()
Rhod.close()
x = text.split('\n')

f = np.loadtxt(x, delimiter=',', skiprows=1, unpack=True)

x = f[0]
y = f[1]
```

I've changed array using np.loadtext.
But I'm stuck here

I have used

```
for x in range(330,900):
    print(int(max(y)))
```

But this one prints whole array of y, (900-330) times.

Thanks guys!

Comment: in your last code snippet you loop with the variable `x` but print `y`. that may not be what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read in the data that you show, one needs to use `delimiter = ' '` instead of `,`. But that could be an issue of copying.

Now having two arrays where you want to find the value of the one (`x`) at the position where the other (`y`) is maximal, you can do

```
x[np.argmax(y)]
```

wherre [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) finds the index of the maximum value.

Directly using `x`, `y` would of course give the unwanted result around 190. So you first need to slice the array. In your case it seems that the step between x values is equal and `1`. This makes it extremely easy:

```
xc = x[330-int(x.min()):]
yc = y[330-int(x.min()):]
print xc[np.argmax(yc)]
```

For the more general case you can use boolean slicing,

```
xc = x[x >= 330]
yc = y[x >= 330]
print xc[np.argmax(yc)]
```

*Just to make sure there is no other mistake in the background: While the file you read in is called `Rhodamine`, the graph you show cannot be Rhodamine, because it has an absorption in the yellow/green (~550 nm) and not at 420 nm.*

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I did use my sample's absorbance instead of Rhodamine B. Good catch! Anyway Thank you so much.